# How to add new constraint for existing declared function in z3 using c++?

Tags: z3

I would like to know is there any way to add some new constraints for existing declared variables in the solver without getting the model.

For example, if I have 2 declare functions:

```
(declare-fun k!648 () (_ BitVec 8))
(declare-fun k!647 () (_ BitVec 8))
```

and some constraint with it.

How can I get their declared names generally?

The situation is that I want to add more constraints for the existing "variables?" in the constraint and solver them together. But I am confused about how to get existing "variables?" and then form the new constraint which is also correct for the solver.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're asking. Note that `k!648` and `k!647` in your example are not actually functions, they are just 8-bit vectors. (The name `declare-fun` is confusing, admittedly.)

The first thing to understand is where are these names coming from? Is it in the script you're feeding to z3? Then you're asking the wrong party here: You should ask the program/system that generated this benchmark. z3 can generate such names, but only in models.

Try providing a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Actually, I generate the constraint from the symbolic execution. The situation is that I want to add more constraints for the existing "variables?" in the constraint and solver them together.  But I am confused about how to get existing "variables?" and then form the new constraint which is also correct for the solver.